# In jQuery, how does prepend() work on a children() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am a little confused on how prepend acts towards a children function.

```
image.canvas.children('.image-pinpoint-view').prepend(this.area);
```

where would this.area appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It adds `this.area` (or a clone) as the first child of every matching child of `image.canvas`.  Matching children are those with the `image-pinpoint-view` class.  A DOM node can only be in one place, but jQuery will clone the element so there's one for each desired parent.

Answer (score 0):

Prepend puts the specified content at the beginning of the element.

```
<div id="content">
   <div id="a">data</div>
</div>

$('#content').prepend('<div id="b">prepended data</div>');
```

would result in

```
<div id="content">
   <div id="b">prepended data</div>
   <div id="a">data</div>
</div>

$('#content').prepend( $('#a') );
```

would result in

```
<div id="content">
       <div id="a">data</div>
       <div id="b">prepended data</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every **jQuery object is an array**. Every jQuery method is applied to all elements. 
If you write:

```
 $(".elements").css(...)
```

...the style will be applied to all elements.

Similarly, in your case, the element (this.area) will be cloned and one clone will be inserted before each children.

[See it in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/tq54g/)

Comment: not _Always_ the case if the element is already a child. instead of cloned, it's index is adjusted. http://jsfiddle.net/tq54g/1/